# How to do JNDI lookup with OracleAQ?

Tags: jms, message-queue, oracle-aq

Can anybody point me some guide/idea on how to implement JNDI lookup with OracleAQ?
( Creating connectionFacotry, parameters for "java.naming.factory.initial", java.naming.provider.url etc..)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to setup a basic JMS (including the lookup of the connection factory) in Oracle WebLogic:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13727/implement.htm#i1317694

Here is another link more specific to Oracle AQ
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13738/aq_jms.htm#JMSAD565

It looks like oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory might be the correct JNDI Initial Context Factory.